# servicestack routing - how do you ignore the query string parameters

Tags: routes, servicestack

For security reasons I want to ignore/disallow all query string parameters.

I.e.

```
POST http://myservice/person
{name:"john"}
//should populate the Name property in my request model


POST http://myservice/person?name=john
//should NOT populate the Name property
```

Can this be acheived in sevicestack without explicitly checking the query string in each service method?

I want to do this because some servers will log URLs in plain text, after SSL decoding, and I want to ensure sensitive parameter values are not logged in any hosting environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any logic to apply globally, you can use a [global filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) or a `PreRequestFilter` which [gets run before any other filter or request binding](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations):

```
this.PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) =>
{
    if (req.QueryString.Count > 0)
    {
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        res.StatusDescription = "Query Strings are not allowed";
        res.EndServiceStackRequest();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, mythz. You're the bomb! However, EndServiceStackRequest() does not seem to exist in that context. I am having success with simply res.End()

Comment: No use `httpRes.EndServiceStackRequest()` to properly end the request. It's an [extension method in ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/Extensions/IHttpResponseExtensions.cs#L382)

Comment: Thanks again. That is working a treat. Perhaps you can also shed some light on this, similar issue?: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183619/with-servicestack-how-can-i-prevent-cookies-being-added-to-the-response