# with servicestack how can i prevent cookies being added to the response?

Tags: session, cookies, http-headers, servicestack, httpresponse

I can remove the cookies after the fact, with this:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    ResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
    {
        ((HttpListenerResponse)res.OriginalResponse).Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
    });
}
```

I have also considered overriding the SetCookie method of HttpResponse to just ditch the cookies, but I am not sure how to override that behaviour in servicestack.

**Question:**
How can I ensure no cookies are added to my responses in the first place? This seems more efficient and fit-to-intent than the above.

**Background:**

I am using Basic Authentication, but I do not need to persist sessions, or want to allow any kind of authentication via cookies. Clients must re-authenticate each request.

So, another approach might also work, such as a custom session factory that returns null sessions? Or some other way of overriding session/authentication handling. However, despite much digging, I have had no success on that front, either.

Thanks in advance!